# PostgreSql: how to write that sql query ? ( schema defined )

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM test;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 5
 4 | 1
 2 | 5
 3 | 3
 1 | 1
(5 rows)
```

How can i write such query, so all output values in "a" column are distinct and all output values in "b" column are also distinct.

So, for example, valid result set for above query is:

```
 1 | 5
 4 | 1
 3 | 3
```

Next one is also valid:

```
 4 | 1
 2 | 5
 3 | 3
```

It is better to find as many results as possible, but it's not a requirement.
What is the best way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: What if there were not equal? I mean you had 3 distinct values on A and 5 distinct values on be. Then what's gonna be as the result?

Comment: why `1|5` and not `2|5`?

Comment: @Ankur, it was an example result set. There could be 2|5 instead of 1|5 - it does not matter for me.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi, from your example you can take any rows with distinct "a" value, which exactly its does not matter.

Comment: So could you please show us how the exact result set would be? Without the correct input, there is no ouput.

Comment: So `1|3` would also be valid in the result set? What happens if there are three distinct `a` values but 11 distinct `b` values?

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi he did... he has both correct input and output.

Comment: @muistooshort you still get one row for any distinct value on either a or b

Comment: That question description is nonsensical. If all distinct "a" values must appear, then `2` must appear in the "a" values list in the results, which it does not. You've posted an answer, but it answers a different question to this one.

Comment: Please fix this contradictory question or delete it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, you did not get it. "a" with value "2" can not appear in result set, because "b" with value = "5" already exists. I can remove "1|5" and add "2|5", and it will be also correct output. ( May be i am not so good in english to explain it better )

Comment: Edited post. I hope now its explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution myself! :)

a) add id column to "test" table 
b) sql query:

```
 WITH 
    t1 AS ( SELECT a, MIN(id) as id FROM test GROUP BY a ), 
    t2 AS ( SELECT b, MIN(id) as id FROM test GROUP BY b ) 
    SELECT * FROM test 
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM t1 ) AND id IN ( SELECT id FROM t2 );
```

Result:

```
 id | a | b 
----+---+---
  6 | 1 | 5
  7 | 4 | 1
  9 | 3 | 3
```

Comment: You never mentioned you had an ID column in that table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, read my answer more carefully ( hint: point "a" )

Comment: I *think* this solution is a little bit over simplified.  If your data are `1, 1`, `2, 1`, `1, 2`, `2, 2` then your code will only return one row; `1, 1`.  Would that really be correct?

Comment: @Dems, Yes, it would be appropriate for me.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov then you could have just picked the first row, that would have been fine

Comment: This is a perfect answer to a different question. Which one is right? I guess we'll never know.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov If that's correct then your problem statement is wrong, because Dems' example would have to produce a result that included `2` in both the 1st and 2nd cols to be correct.

Comment: Based on the edit to your question, and the comment you also made: for the input of `1,1`, `1,2`, `1,2`, `2,2` you want the results `1,2`, `2,1`.  Yet, your answer and comment here say that just returning `1,1` would be correct.  You need to work out your requirements more clearly.

Comment: @Dems, thanks for comment. Ok, lets read again requirement from my post: `all output values in "a" column are distinct and all output values in "b" column are also distinct`. Question: does my answer on your question contradict that requirement ?) The answer is obvious: no. I did not say anything about output results count. P.s. Of course its better to find as many results as you can

Comment: @OlegGolovanov - Then your requirement can be full-filled by returning zero records.  All values in field a would then be unique, and so would all values in field b.  Or just pick the first record and ignore *all* the others.  Oh, wait, you say `Of course its better to find as many results as you can`?  If that's the case then where your code return just one row for my example, and I can show that it's possible to return 2 rows, which is right?  Because if there is no `right` answer how on earth do you expect people on SO to be able to answer your vague and non-deterministic question?

Comment: @Dems, i expect people here not to be so stupid to propose me solution that returns zero record, or one first record :)

Comment: @OlegGolovanov - For the example data set that I have mentioned in a comment here, returning just the first record is *exactly* what *you* do...

Comment: @Dems, i am not returning one record. Its my query from your input set returns one first result, where at max two results possible. Just for your input i expect this behaviour to be ok. If i'll edit my post and add something like "Requirement: query must return at least 50% of maximum possible results", would you be glad?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think this should also give you correct output:
    SELECT a, MIN(b) as b FROM test GROUP BY a
    Intersect
    SELECT min(a) as a, b  FROM test GROUP BY b;</strike>

EDIT:Try this:

```
Select MIN(t1.a), t1.b from (SELECT a, MIN(b) as b FROM test GROUP BY a) t1 GROUP BY t1.b
```

Comment: Doesn't work, result set `(3, 3), (1, 1)`

Comment: this one works, result set I got (1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 3)

Comment: @xception where are you trying? are there alternate sites to sqlfiddle? it seems to have gone out of memory

Comment: I also was thinking about using 2 group by clauses, didn't figure how to separate them though, you got my vote.

Comment: I'm trying on localhost, the good, old-fashioned way :)

Comment: for future reference there is the code to sqlfiddle on github https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle so you can install it on your machine if you want

Comment: this has the same issue noticed by @Dems on the other reply